# Does Captive Portal block access to FTP-servers?

Tags: ftp

When a user hasn't been authenticated through the Captive Portal, can they access FTP-servers?
I have read that a Captive Portal blocks access to websites via HTTP-requests and it does not work with HTTPS or FTP.

Comment: What works depends on the software being used on how it was configured.  Can you provide specifics?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't provide specific details as I just wanted to know about the general functioning of Captive Portals.
But your comment shows that Captive Portals can be configured in different ways and that decides what should be blocked.
Your comment was actually kinda the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a captive portal blocks any access to outside (sometimes it allows DNS) and redirects HTTP requests to some portal page. Only after the user is logged in or whatever the portal requires the access to outside is unblocked. This means FTP will not work if the user is not yet authenticated.